# Accessing the members of a simple class in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a simple Java class which extends `View` in another package, and I am making a custom view using this class. I want to use it as a `View` in XML from another class, which is an `Activity`.

My custom `View` needs some data from that class, so I created an object of `Pt` class, which extends `Activity`.  The object is created, but when I am use that object for accessing the members of the class that extends `Activity`, it does not show any members. Am I doing something wrong, or there is a better way to do it?

Here is my code. I have shown what I am expecting within the comments.

```
public class PlotView extends View {//class to make a custom view

    Plot_View obj_plot = new Plot_View();
    obj_plot.//  here i am expecting it to show the members of that Plot_View class which is extending Activity 

    class Pt{
        float x, y;
        Pt(float _x, float _y){
            x = _x;
            y = _y;
        }
    }

    Pt[] myPath = { new Pt(100, 100), new Pt(200, 200),    new Pt(200, 500),
                    new Pt(400, 500),    new Pt(400, 200) };

    public PlotView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public PlotView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(myPath[0].x, myPath[0].y);

        for (int i = 1; i < myPath.length; i++){
            path.lineTo(myPath[i].x, myPath[i].y);
        }
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}//
```

and here is my Plot_View Activity .i want to access these Arraylists defined here in this activity

```
     public class Plot_View extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.plotview);

      calculationForPlot();

    findViewById(R.id.btn_measure).setOnClickListener(this);



     initMirrorMatrix();

     drawMatrix();
}

 private void calculationForPlot(){
     ArrayList<String> al_edit_A_ft = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> al_edit_A_inch=new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String>al_edit_B_ft=new ArrayList<String>(); 
     ArrayList<String>al_edit_B_inch= new ArrayList<String>();
    float x=0;
     AndroidOpenDbHelper androidOpenDbHelperObj = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = androidOpenDbHelperObj.getReadableDatabase();
        String q="SELECT * FROM ab_measurement WHERE job_id=" +"\""+Settings.jobid +"\"";


   Cursor  cursor = sqliteDatabase.rawQuery(q,null);

        if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.getCount());
            m=Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4));

            do {
                try{

                float a = 0,b = 0;



                 a=(float) Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(6));
                 String number =String.valueOf(a);
                 System.out.println("aaa ggg"+number);
                 String int_part =number.substring(0,number.indexOf("."));
                 String float_part=number.substring(number.lastIndexOf(".")+1,number.length());
                 System.out.println("aaa values"+int_part);
                 System.out.println("aaa values"+float_part);


                  al_edit_A_ft.add(int_part);
                  al_edit_A_inch.add(float_part);

                     b= (float) Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(7));
                     String number_b =String.valueOf(b);
                     System.out.println("aaa ggg"+number_b);
                     String int_part_b =number_b.substring(0,number_b.indexOf("."));
                     String float_part_b=number_b.substring(number_b.lastIndexOf(".")+1,number_b.length());
                     System.out.println("aaa values"+int_part_b);
                     System.out.println("aaa values"+float_part_b);
                     al_edit_B_ft.add(int_part_b);
                     al_edit_B_inch.add(float_part_b);

                     x= (float) Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(3));
                     String ft_base =String.valueOf(x);
                     System.out.println("aaa ggg"+ft_base);
                     String int_part_ft =ft_base.substring(0,ft_base.indexOf("."));
                     String float_part_inch=ft_base.substring(ft_base.lastIndexOf(".")+1,ft_base.length());
                     System.out.println("aaa values"+int_part_ft);
                     System.out.println("aaa values"+float_part_inch);


                }
                catch (Exception e) {

                }

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Comment: I edited my answer to help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

Try this....

**Create an object reference variable of** `Your_Activity` **type in the Java class, and initialize it in the contructor  with the** `Context` **passed to it.**

**Activity class:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
TextView myView ;
protected void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myView);
        Points myPoints = new Points(this);
        myPoints.displayMsg("MY NAME IS VIVEK");
}  
}
```

**Java class:**

```
    private class Points {

    public MyActivity mcontext;

    ////---------- a constructor with the Context of your activity

    public Points(MyActivity context){
        mcontext = context;
    }

    public void displayMsg( final String msg){
        context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                mcontext.myView.setText(msg);    
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the way your commented line of code is incomplete, I assume you are using an auto-complete feature of your IDE.

My first suggestion is to change the name `Plot_View` to `PlotActivity`. This will help you avoid confusion when you return to this project in the future. Also, it will help avoid confusion when you ask questions here.

As for your actualy question, I assume you are referring to the following `ArrayList`s:

```
ArrayList<String> al_edit_A_ft = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> al_edit_A_inch=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String>al_edit_B_ft=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String>al_edit_B_inch= new ArrayList<String>();
```

First you need to realize that these are *not* members of the `Plot_View` class. They are declared locally in the `calculationForPlot()` method. Although, it appears that you have not posted the entire `Plot_View` class, so you may have declared other `ArrayList`s elsewhere. If you are indeed referring to the `ArrayList`s that I pasted above, you will need to declare them as member variables in `Plot_View` rather than as local variables in `calculationForPlot()`. Then you can create getter methods to allow your `View` class to access them.

Comment: sir let me explain. Plot_View is an activity declared in another package and PlotView (without underscore) is my custom view class from where ill make a view having a graph and will use it n Plot_View Activity directly . now for grah i need some points and those points are in Plot_View Activity from there i want those points to come in my PlotView class (which is a custom view class)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Let me first suggest that you change the name `Plot_View` to `PlotActivity`. Having two names that differ by a single character can easily lead to confusion (for yourself as much as everyone else). Second, is my first assumption correct that you are trying to use an auto-complete feature in your IDE? Third, please post enough of your `Plot_View` class to add to further clarify what you are doing.

Comment: ok..thanxx for the suggestion ill do that,ya u r ryt i am trying to use auto complete feature and wait ill post dt activity class too

Comment: One additional suggestion: Please take the time to type out full words and use correct spelling. I am quite aware that this is an international forum, so I try to be understanding of anyone who does not speak English as their native language. However, using abreviations for words (like "u" instead of "you" and "r" instead of "are") make it harder to read and understand what you are asking.

Comment: i will keep this in my mind from now onwards.And i posted that Activity class.Now if you can help ?